# Django model with list of items

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am writing simple model of phonebook.

I have object `Person` and `Contact`

Every person can have multiple contacts.

I have two approaches of modelling, but I am not sure which one is correct.

First approach:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
     phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Contact', blank=True)
```

Second approach:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    possessor = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name='possessor')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
```

I am not sure which approach is better (and correct?) and later easier to make queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first allows a `Contact` to belong to more than one `Person`. The second only allows a `Contact` to belong to a single `Person`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think one contact can belong only to one person. Since I would like to store name of that contact (which every person can set for their contacts). Do you think that is good approach?

Comment: It sounds like your requirements are directing you towards the second scheme.

Answer (score 0):

****** write the below code in the your views.py file

def my_view(request):
    all_categories = Category.objects.all()

******write the below code in the HTML File

{% for category in all_categories %}